# Get index of selected character

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working on a macro, which iterates over all characters of the active document:

```
Dim index As Integer
index = Selection.Start

Dim counter As Integer
counter = 0

MsgBox Selection.Characters(1)

For Each c In ActiveDocument.Characters
    If counter < index Then
        counter = counter + 1
    Else
        MsgBox c.Font.Name
    End If
Next
```

By the first `If` statement I want to skip all characters until my selection marker.

My problem is that index exceeds the max. character count (maybe because of images) leading to a wrong loop.

For example: Index shows 2889, but my character count of the whole document is only 1238.

How do I get the position of the selected character?

Comment: How are you getting your character count? By using Word Count in the proofing section of the review tab, or with `ActiveDocument.Characters.Count`? It's important to note that the VBA of `Characters.Count` will also include carriage returns (as well as other spacing characters, I'm sure).

Answer (score 0):

Working with the `Start` or `End` positions is unreliable due to the way Word handles non-visible content. It's fine for setting the Start of one Range to the End of another, for example, but not for exact location within the document.

For the task described in the question the `Range.InRange` method will work. This returns True if the Range passed as an argument contains the Range on which the method is called. For example:

```
Dim index As Word.Range
Set index = Selection.Range

Dim counter As Integer
counter = 0

MsgBox Selection.Characters(1)

For Each c In ActiveDocument.Characters
    If c.InRange(Index) Then
        counter = counter + 1
    Else
        MsgBox c.Font.Name
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

### Start/End Positions

Any `.Start` or `.End` values is Word's internal exact positioning, including further detail information than just the amount of characters. These position numbers are higher than the number of characters. Examples:

- `ActiveDocument.Content.End`
- `Selection.End` (especially if you selected the whole document for example)

### Characters.Count

The amount of characters can be counted on a Range. It includes all character types like spaces, paragraph marks and also hidden characters.

- `ActiveDocument.Characters.Count`
- `ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).Characters.Count`
- `Selection.Characters.Count`

**Example**

[image: Example for .Count vs. .End]
This example document contains only 7 characters, but the middle "1" is a page number in a field. Words counts as follows:

- `ActiveDocument.Characters.Count` = 8
  (Upper example when fields are not shown: 8 = 6 digits + page number + paragraph)
- `ActiveDocument.Characters.Count` = 32
  (Lower example when fields are shown: 32 = all visible characters including braces)
- `ActiveDocument.Content.End` = 34
  (Braces for the field are special characters and count additionally)

### Cursor's Character Position

You can build a range with the cursor's position to get it's character position (please use data type `Long` for documents with more than 32.767 characters):

```
Dim pos As Long
pos = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Start + 1).Characters.Count
```

### Cursor's Font Name

Following code shows the font name of the character directly **left** of the cursor position *like Word itself does* in the font dropdown menu (slow).

```
Dim pos As Long
pos = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Start).Characters.Count
MsgBox ActiveDocument.Characters(pos).Font.Name
```

If you just need the font of the first character of your selection, simply use following faster version. It shows the font name of the first selected character. If you didn' select anything, it delivers the font name directly **right** of the cursor:

```
MsgBox Selection.Characters(1).Font.Name
```

Comment: Did you give my answer a try? If it works fine for you, please consider to mark it as answer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). If not, don't hesitate to comment here below it.