# Sending a range of cells as Rich Text email (outlook) and also add as attachment using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word, office-automation

There is already a lot of answers about sending excel range to outlook email, But they all compose the message as **HTML** format.
I found this code [Link](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-methods-quickly-send-selected-cells-excel-worksheet-outlook-email/) and adapted a little to also include the selection as attachment file and it works as HTML format without Problem.
Instead of HTML format , I need to automate sending the same range of cells as `Rich Text email` (outlook) using Excel vba.
**In the body of the email I need the following**:
1- include a portion of a spreadsheet (Selection) formatted as a table.
2- Insert attachment under that table (It will appear as an icon).
3- then sure the signature. 
I can manually do all these tasks, So it is probable it can be done by using Excel VBA.
On the below code, If I made objNewEmail.BodyFormat `= olFormatRichText` and changed objNewEmail. HTMLBody with `objNewEmail.RTFBody`
**Then I got the following issue**: 
A- The email message created (composted as Rich text) and cells range attached as a file on the body and after that signature.
B- The range selection itself is not inserted on the body at all.
C- and I got this error on the line of objNewEmail.RTFBody=

> Run-time error '-1594818561 (a0f0ffff)':The operation failed

I have to show my full code to make it easier for anyone interested to help me.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
 
Sub Sending_Range_as_Rich_Text_email_from_Outlook_using_Excel()
 
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
    Dim objSelection As Excel.Range
    Set objSelection = Selection: objSelection.Copy
 
    Dim objTempWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Set objTempWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    Dim objTempWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Set objTempWorksheet = objTempWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 
    Dim strTempHTMLFile As String, Strbody As String
    Dim objTempHTMLFile As Object, objTextStream As Object
 
    Dim objFileSystem As Object
    Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 
    Dim objOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNewEmail As Outlook.MailItem
 
'Pasting into a Temp Worksheet
     With objTempWorksheet.Cells(1)
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
     End With
 
'Save the Temp Worksheet as a HTML File
     strTempHTMLFile = objFileSystem.GetSpecialFolder(2).path & "\Temp for Excel" & Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss") & ".htm"
     Set objTempHTMLFile = objTempWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, strTempHTMLFile, objTempWorksheet.Name, objTempWorksheet.UsedRange.Address)
     objTempHTMLFile.Publish (True)
 
'Create a new Email
     Set objOutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
     Set objNewEmail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
     objNewEmail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
 
'Insert the Temp Worksheet into the Email Body
    Dim wb1 As Workbook:        Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String: TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    Dim TempFileName As String: TempFileName = "Output Data"
    Dim FileExtStr As String:   FileExtStr = ".xlsx"
 
    wb1.SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    objNewEmail.Attachments.Add TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
'_________________________
     objNewEmail.Display
     Set objTextStream = objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(strTempHTMLFile)
     Strbody = "<h4>Dears,</h4>" & "<br>"
     objNewEmail.HTMLBody = Strbody & "<table style='Margin-Left:25pt'>" & _
                            objTextStream.ReadAll & "</Table>" & objNewEmail.HTMLBody
     objTextStream.Close
     objTempWorkbook.Close (False)
     objFileSystem.DeleteFile (strTempHTMLFile)
     Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr 'Delete the temp Excel File
 
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Consider adding the ms-word tag.

Comment: @niton added the ms-word tag and I will feed you back tomorrow morning (I will have access to my work PC)

Answer (score 1):

In this code the attachment appears before the formatted signature.

The method used to determine the `Position` parameter in `.Attachments.Add TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, , attPos` may have to be adjusted for your case.

```vb
Sub SendEmail_PositionAttachmentAboveSignature()
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    ' Application is Excel. No influence in Outlook.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Reference Microsoft Outlook nn.n Object Library
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olInsp As Outlook.Inspector
    
    ' Reference Microsoft Word nn.n Object Library
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    
    Dim strGreeting As String
    
    Dim objSelection As Excel.Range
    Set objSelection = Selection
    objSelection.Copy
    
    Dim objTempWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Set objTempWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    
    Dim objTempWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Set objTempWorksheet = objTempWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 
    Dim strTempHTMLFile As String, Strbody As String
    Dim objTempHTMLFile As Object, objTextStream As Object
 
    Dim objFileSystem As Object
    Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    'Pasting into a Temp Worksheet
     With objTempWorksheet.Cells(1)
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
     End With
 
    'Save the Temp Worksheet as a HTML File
    strTempHTMLFile = objFileSystem.GetSpecialFolder(2).Path & _
      "\Temp for Excel" & Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    Set objTempHTMLFile = objTempWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, _
      strTempHTMLFile, objTempWorksheet.Name, objTempWorksheet.UsedRange.Address)
    objTempHTMLFile.Publish (True)
    
    strGreeting = "Dear Someone," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    With olEmail
        
        .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector  ' A side effect is to get the signature
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        
        Dim lenSignature As Long
        lenSignature = Len(.Body)
        
        Debug.Print lenSignature
        
        wdDoc.Range.InsertBefore strGreeting
        wdDoc.Paragraphs(3).Range.Paste
        
        'Alternative if you can figure out how to place it where you want
        ' wdDoc.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
        
        ' I found it necessary or the attachment did not appear
        .Display
        
        'Insert the Temp Worksheet into the Email Body
        Dim wb1 As Workbook:        Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
        Dim TempFilePath As String: TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
        Dim TempFileName As String: TempFileName = "Output Data"
        Dim FileExtStr As String:   FileExtStr = ".xlsx"
        
        Debug.Print TempFilePath & TempFileName
        wb1.SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        
        ' Placed at end of email
        '.Attachments.Add TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
        '
        ' You could try "Position" to place the attachment within the body.
        '  This parameter applies only to email messages using the Rich Text format.
        '  Possibly based on length of signature.
        '  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add
        
        Dim sigStart As Long
        ' On my machine this is not the position of the start of the signature
        sigStart = Len(.Body) - lenSignature
        
        Dim attPos As Long  ' Character position for the attachment
        ' Intuitively attPos would be sigStart - 1
        '
        ' Possible non-visible content impact?
        '  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54298911/1571407
        '
        ' In my tests the position appears related to
        '  the number of newlines in strGreeting
        '  the number of rows in the selection.
        Dim attPosAdjustment As Long
        attPosAdjustment = objSelection.Rows.Count
        Debug.Print "attPosAdjustment: " & attPosAdjustment
        attPos = sigStart - attPosAdjustment
        Debug.Print "attPos: " & attPos
        .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, , attPos
        
        ' Likely there is a Word VBA approach,
        '  possibly using wdDoc.Bookmarks("_MailAutoSig")
        '  to position the attachment above the signature.
        ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70114895/vba-detect-if-an-e-mail-in-editing-mode-has-a-signature-included

    End With

    objTempWorkbook.Close (False)
    objFileSystem.DeleteFile (strTempHTMLFile)
    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr 'Delete the temp Excel File
    
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olEmail = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

[How to paste multiple table ranges into Outlook body using Word Editor (As Images)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57896028/how-to-paste-multiple-table-ranges-into-outlook-body-using-word-editor-as-image) shows how WordEditor can be used.

Assigning the signature to a text variable makes it is easier to place the attachment appropriately.

```vb
Sub SendEmail_NoFormattingSig()

    ' Reference Microsoft Outlook nn.n Object Library
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olInsp As Outlook.Inspector
    
    ' Reference Microsoft Word nn.n Object Library
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim strGreeting As String
    Dim strSignature As String
    
    Dim objSelection As Excel.Range
    
    Set objSelection = Selection
    objSelection.Copy
        
    strGreeting = "Dear Someone," & vbNewLine
    
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With olEmail
    
        .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        .Display
        
        ' Formatting lost if there is a default signature
        strSignature = .Body
        .Body = ""
        
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        
        wdDoc.Range.InsertBefore vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        
        wdDoc.Paragraphs(2).Range.Paste
        
        'Alternative if you can figure out how to position where you want
        ' wdDoc.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting

        wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbNewLine
        
        Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Attachments.Add (ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
        
        wdDoc.Range.InsertBefore strGreeting
        
        wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter strSignature
        
    End With
    
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olEmail = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: this my feedback after I test, **(1)** the `selection cells` inserted on the body without problem.
**(2)** the attached file inserted after copied data ,**But** it is the full main workbook and not the selection as expected.
**(3)** the format of my signature is not correct and without picture.
**(4)**  the screen of email is flickering, even after I used `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at beginning of code.
I can manually do all these tasks, So it is probable it can be done by using VBA.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Your last code works good, But with a small issue that the attached file is inserted on the last below right cell on the table (found on the body).
Kindly see this picture  https://easyupload.io/269gi6

Comment: Wrong test version. Three `vbNewLine`s in  `strGreeting = "Dear Someone," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine`. This method requires a little care in accounting for the number of characters.  You could instead have moved the table up `wdDoc.Paragraphs(2).Range.Paste`.

Comment: Now all works 

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Word object model to copy the required data from Excel and paste it to the message body represented by the Word document.

To get the signature added to the message body you need to call the `Display` method prior to making any modifications to the message body.

Note, there are three main ways of dealing with message bodies in Outlook:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the `Inspector` class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases for almost static email you can use pre-generated RTF mail body. You can use some placeholders in RTF and replace them during email generation. Here is sample code for static email with table (without file attachment)

```vb
Sub CreateRtfMail()
    
    Dim outlookApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim eMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set eMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    eMail.BodyFormat = olFormatRichText

    eMail.Body = _
        "{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1250\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1029\deflangfe1029{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset238 Calibri;}{\f1\fnil Calibri;}{\f2\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}" & vbCrLf & _
        "{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}" & vbCrLf & _
        "{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.19041}{\*\mmathPr\mdispDef1\mwrapIndent1440 }\viewkind4\uc1 " & vbCrLf & _
        "\pard\sa200\sl240\slmult1\f0\fs22 Greetings\par" & vbCrLf & _
        "Body of message\par" & vbCrLf & _
        "\trowd\trgaph30\trleft-30\trrh290\trpaddl30\trpaddr30\trpaddfl3\trpaddfr3" & vbCrLf & _
        "\cellx1002\cellx2034 " & vbCrLf & _
        "\pard\intbl\cf1\f1 Adam1\cell Bob1\cell\row\trowd\trgaph30\trleft-30\trrh290\trpaddl30\trpaddr30\trpaddfl3\trpaddfr3" & vbCrLf & _
        "\cellx1002\cellx2034 " & vbCrLf & _
        "\pard\intbl Adam2\cell Bob2\cell\row " & vbCrLf & _
        "\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\cf0\f0\par" & vbCrLf & _
        "Sign\f2\lang5\par" & vbCrLf & _
        "}" & vbCrLf
    
    eMail.Display
    
End Sub
```

I have the best experience with WordPad for RTF file creation instead of MS Word

Answer (score 0):

Sends the active selection as a table. Hope it helps!

```
Sub ExtReqForm_SendEmail()
'Update 20131209
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
'SET RANGE HERE OR USE INPUT BOX TO SELECT
Set WorkRng = Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("A1:A2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
WorkRng.Select
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
    .Introduction = ""
    .Item.To = ""
    .Item.CC = ""
    .Item.Subject = ""
    .Item.Send
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
'''
```